# Generate signature of RSA key give wrong data

Tags: c#, php, .net, rsa, phpseclib

I am using https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib to generate signature. But when i generate signature with my RSA private key it is generated signature but it also give me `unverified` when i verify with my public key .

Here is my code :

```
<?php

// Include library
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

// Create an Instance
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$hash = new Crypt_Hash('sha256');

$data = array(
     "name" => "hello"
);

$data = json_encode($data, true);

// Load Private Key
$rsa->loadKey('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAlwK9IAETYwSW6p0hVEue3+WyMtRW5MA3BS2Bzf3B0Qimnvfl
....
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----');

// Message to be signed
$plaintext = $data;

// Set signing signature
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$hashed = $hash->hash($plaintext); 
$encrypted = $rsa->sign($hashed); // Sign Data
$signature = base64_encode($encrypted); // Encode to base64 the signed Data

echo $signature;

$rsa->loadKey('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlwK9IAETYwSW6p0hVEue
.....
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'); // public key
echo $rsa->verify($plaintext, $signature) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';
```

Now above code generate signature but it is not correct.

Now after this i have tried `BouncyCastle` lib to generate signature with above keys only in .NET . It is generated perfect signature & also it is verified.

I do not know what is the problem with `phpseclib` lib. I have also directly try to generate with openssl but still it is not generating correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues:

- The data to be signed must be passed to the `sign` method and not the hash of these data. The `sign` method performs the hashing itself. By default, sha1 is used as digest. A different digest must be specified explicitly with `setHash`.
- The signature must be passed to the `verify` method and not the Base64 encoded signature.

Try the following modifications:

```
...
$rsa->setHash('sha256');                                                         // Specify digest, e.g. sha256 (default is sha1)
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$signature = $rsa->sign($plaintext);                                             // Pass plaintext instead of plaintext hash.
echo base64_encode($signature) . "\n";
...
echo $rsa->verify($plaintext, $signature) ? 'verified' : 'unverified' . "\n";    // Pass signature instead of Base64 encoded signature
...
```

There is also a corresponding [example](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html#sign,pkcs1,pkcs1pub,sign2,enc1,1.0,) in the documentation.

---

**Update:**

The specification `SignerUtilities.GetSigner("RSA")` in the C# code means that the data are signed *without* prior hashing, i.e. therefore the hashing must be *explicitly* performed before, which is also the case in the current C# code (using SHA256).

However, this way differs from the standard [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2) (described in RFC 8017) in that RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 places a digest ID before the hash (in the case of SHA256, this is the ID [`0x3031300d060960864801650304020105000420`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#page-47)). For this reason, verification with the *phpseclib*, which (of course) uses RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5, fails.

To also use RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 in the C# code, either add the digest ID manually or use `SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA")` so that the data are hashed before signing (then of course the *explicit* hashing must be omitted).

---

If the C# code is the reference, then a library is needed that can be used to sign without prior hashing, analogous to the C# code.

*phpseclib* uses `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` padding for signing/verifying (for the signature mode `CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1`) and the different `RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5` padding for encryption/decryption (for the encryption mode `CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1`). Neither of these are therefore options here.

As noted in @neubert's comment, *phpseclib* offers the possibility to disable padding during encryption/decryption (for the encryption mode `CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_NONE` padding is done with `0x00` values). This allows a custom signing by implementing a custom padding followed by encryption with the private key. In the current case, this would require the implementation of `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` padding *without* the part where the digest ID is added.

Easier here is to use alternatives that *already* apply `RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5` padding *if* the digest ID and hash are provided, which in the current case means that only the hash needs to be passed. Examples of such alternatives are [`openssl_private_encrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-encrypt.php) for signing and [`openssl_public_decrypt`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-decrypt.php) for verifying:

```
$data = array(
    "name" => "hello"
);
$data = json_encode($data, true);

$hashed = hash('sha256', $data, true);                            // Hash data using sha256

// Signing
openssl_private_encrypt($hashed, $signature, $privateKey);        // Encrypt data using the private key
echo base64_encode($signature) . "\n";                            // Output: csorNNekiVXJzQaT/FVCKrlSPfonQYw7dStKsjgVuW/jAcRafk4Yeuzw4rc1WxfgheMaa31DROnhrRCBS6VNUm8w2N/XwX2zmImFLj5KZlnRPne7CZX3YHM3qa5CRf/1VWdNnXMZnBecIe6QltECQLsQ/8fRzaYJpZO6tZjIRf4fBYwqMHWhHlTn6UR3A0GDKSEU5mI2lvzl+9ov+x6AFCLT3sa8hc3aZDfO7SWmQHNHCwrBC9QFNTOHY+/oJXtKYMfY3IskvLSmKmvKc6vh8XANBYp+NCl3/9hNdhbF4psdJXuZgf3aSpy0koBttdcE3js0NoS8Q91ry2WJtkcCrA==

// Verifying
openssl_public_decrypt($signature, $decrypted, $publicKey);       // Decrypt data using the public key
$verified = ($decrypted == $hashed) ? 'verified' : 'unverified';  // Verify data 
echo $verified;
```

Comment: Ok. Got it but still the generated signature is different. Generated wrong signature.

Comment: @deepak - Note that the identifier must be in lower case, i.e. `sha256`, otherwise the digest will not be recognized and simply the default digest `sha1` will be used. It is best if you post a private _test_ key, as well as the expected and the currently generated signature.

Comment: Updated with my private key and expected signature.

Comment: Are you sure that for both signatures 1. `sha256`, 2. the same padding and 3. the same data (to be signed) are used? The signature `HHN19M1qy...` seems to be correct, which can easily be verified e.g. [here](https://8gwifi.org/rsasignverifyfunctions.jsp) with `SHA256withRSA`. Can you post the C# code that generates the other signature?

Comment: The reason for the issue is that the C# code doesn't comply with the RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 standard, see the update section in my answer.

Comment: Yes but if i will change that in C# code then it wont work as it gives an error from 3rd party.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210438/discussion-between-deepak-and-topaco).

Comment: If the C# code is the reference you must switch to another library. I've updated my answer. Saw the invitation to the chat too late, am now in chat.

Comment: "_phpseclib cannot be used because sign/verify always uses RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 padding and the encryption with the private key applies the different RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 padding_". That is incorrect. You can do unpadded RSA encryption with phpseclib by doing `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_NONE);`.

Comment: @neubert - True, but the disadvantage is that the padding must be implemented manually. In the current case, this has to be RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 (without ID), so it seems easier here to use alternatives that already apply RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 and only need to be passed ID and hash. Anyway, I've added this information to my answer.